# Automating autoruns-psexec or not

Tags: python, scripting, psexec, autostart, sysinternals

So i'm working on some project to find malware in my network.Trying to automate autoruns(sysinternals)
in order to find anomalies or changes in startup on workstations.to do so i want to make daily reports for multiple workstations each day and check for changes for previous reports(finding differences).
So i need couple of advices:
1.Should i remote execute the script with psexec(sysinternals)? it seems way to risky with high priviliged account .. is there any other way?
2.Any working software for finding diffrence in report(xml, csv, or just text)(easy to use-free and windows) 
I have already tried to make it using c but it is too much effort.should i write it in python or other language like c#...

Answer (score 0):

I would use silentrunners.org to create daily snapshots.  Then you could compare those and should something change flag that system for further review.  Windows has FC which `Compares two files or sets of files and displays the differences between them`

```
FC [/A] [/C] [/L] [/LBn] [/N] [/OFF[LINE]] [/T] [/U] [/W] [/nnnn]
[drive1:][path1]filename1 [drive2:][path2]filename2
FC /B [drive1:][path1]filename1 [drive2:][path2]filename2
```

Comment: can i run it remotely ?

Comment: Of course, use `psexec -s` to run the `CSCRIPT.EXE -nologo slientrunners.vbs` as a system account on the remote machine.  Then direct the output to some network location to use FC to compare the resulant files.

Comment: isn't a bit risky to use psexec ? it has my priviliged credintals on the memory on each workstation i will run it againt...
i thought using wmi may be a bit more secure ? what do u think ?

Comment: PSEXEC can be run under the System account but you are correct PSEXEC will send the password in clear text.